# How to send a JSON while posting a request in ext js store using proxy

Tags: ajax, http, extjs, extjs6

I am new to ext js. I am trying to pass a JSON in the request body to service call. I am using the following code to send JSON in the request. I getting an error response when i do so.

```
Ext.define('MyStore.store.dashboard.graphs.Temp', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'abc.php', 

            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

           params :  JSON.stringify({
                locationID: [],
                startDtTime: "2009-06-10T11:00:00",
                endDtTime: "2016-05-10T11:00:00",                   
                GroupValue:"",
            }) })
```

But when i use Ext.Ajax.request i get a proper response:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({

url: 'abc.php',  

jsonData : data, 

success: function(hxr) {
    console.log(hxr);    
},

failure: function(hxr) {
    console.log(hxr);      
}})
```

I have seen similar posts in the forums. My question is if there is no way to set json in a request using store then can i pass response obtained from Ext.Ajax.request to my store?

Comment: That's not how the store works, you have to pass your params via `store.load({params:{}});`

Comment: I am not sure how that is done. Could you explain how do i integrate that with my code?

Comment: Without more information about what have you done so far, i don't think so. What version are you using of ExtJS? You are using controllers, viewControllers or where did you execute the code you post?

Comment: I am using ext js 6. At the moment i have not written any controllers or view controllers. I am just trying to understand this as i need to build a prototype later. I have just used ext js chart where i fill a graph based on the values in the store. This worked fine when i load it using a static JSON file. But now i need to send certain parameters in a request as a JSON to a server to get a response for  my graph.

Comment: have you try to add record and then sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS always sends POST values as JSON, [except when you submit a form with a file upload field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload).

[But ExtJS store uses GET method for read by default](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-actionMethods), while [`Ext.Ajax.request` uses POST by default if parameters are defined](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request).

But you can explicitly tell the store's proxy to use the POST method:

```
proxy:{
    actionMethods:{
        read:'POST'
    },
    extraParams : {
        locationID: [],
        startDtTime: "2009-06-10T11:00:00",
        endDtTime: "2016-05-10T11:00:00",                   
        GroupValue:"",
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but it still doesnt work. I have checked chromes developer console and it sends a post request which is fine but doesn't show any value in the request's body.

Comment: @NullPointer Sorry, my fault, it's `extraParams` for store proxy, I have updated the code.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as well. although now i happen to see some text like '0=%7B&1=%22&2=l&3=o&4=c&5=a' in request payload

Comment: Thanks.But I need these parameters to be passed as a JSON object, and in  the body of the post request